# What is the right syntax to use std::iter::Iterator::reduce for summation?

Tags: rust, syntax, traits

Among many codes I've tried for this one, this I think is the more concise code to show here:

```rust
fn summation<I>(nums: I) -> Option<I::Item>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: std::ops::Add,
{
    nums.reduce(|a, b| a + b)
}

fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<f32> = vec![1f32, 2f32, 3f32];
    let result = summation(numbers.into_iter());
}
```

My goal is mainly tinkering with the `Iterator::reduce`'s function to increase my understanding with Rust.

The code above spits out the following error when I run `cargo check` in the powershell:

```
    Checking code_demo v0.1.0 (C:\Users\miked\git\code_demo)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\main.rs:6:24
  |
6 |     nums.reduce(|a, b| a + b)
  |                        ^^^^^ expected std::iter::Iterator::Item, found std::ops::Add::Output
  |
  = note: expected associated type `<I as Iterator>::Item`
             found associated type `<<I as Iterator>::Item as Add>::Output`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `code_demo`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I tried to replicate the code on [docs.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce), but the code snippet over there is using
`Ord` trait.

I tried this one as well:

```rust
fn summation<I>(nums: I) -> Option<I::Item>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: std::ops::Add::Output,
{
    nums.reduce(|a, b| a + b)
}

fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<f32> = vec![1f32, 2f32, 3f32];
    let result = summation(numbers.into_iter());
}
```

And running `cargo check` would spit out:

```
    Checking code_demo v0.1.0 (C:\Users\miked\git\code_demo)
error[E0404]: expected trait, found associated type `std::ops::Add::Output`
 --> src\main.rs:4:14
  |
4 |     I::Item: std::ops::Add::Output,
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a trait

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0404`.
error: could not compile `code_demo`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Is there a way I can implement `Add` for the function to get the summation of
vector of integers or vector of floats?

Or is it that what I'm trying to do impossible and just use `use std::iter::Sum;`? If so, how would that be implemented?

Thanks.

edits:
1st Sorry, forgot to remove the generic parameter `T` 
2nd I added other solutions I tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you got the general ideal of the issue. Since `reduce` requires that the reducer function returns `I::Item`, you need to explicitly set up the bounds of `Add` so that it is guaranteed to output the same type that it used as input. The syntax you're looking for is

```
I::Item: std::ops::Add<Output=I::Item>
```

so your code will compile with

```
fn summation<I>(nums: I) -> Option<I::Item>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: std::ops::Add<Output=I::Item>
{
    nums.reduce(|a, b| a + b)
}
```

Comment: Thank you internet stranger!!! may the gods of programming projects shower you with opportunities! =)

Comment: Re-reading your answer lead me to new insights. Really appreciated your help.